# Draw multiple bitmaps on Imageview

Tags: android

I have an imageview which displays an first image. I want to draw second smaller image on top of it. I am using canvas to draw the second image but it doesn't appears. Here I want to check if it's second touch on the imageview then let the second image be drawn. Thanks

```
iv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int action = event.getAction();
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            int countClicked = countClicked + 1;

            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Canvas c = new Canvas(myBitmap);
                c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
                iv2.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                if(countClicked == 2) {
                    c.drawBitmap(secondBitmap, x, y, p)
                }
                break;
            return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
            Canvas c = new Canvas(myBitmap);
            c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);

            if(countClicked == 2) { //Do this before .setImageBitmap
                c.drawBitmap(secondBitmap, x, y, p)
            }

            iv2.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); //This needs to go after you add the second image
```

It was drawing, but it was drawing after you set the image to the view, so it never shows up.

Comment: I checked , countClicked is getting to 2

Comment: But it won't draw on the imageview, I think I am missing something here

Comment: Just to elaborate, I want draw smaller bitmaps on imageview in the onTouch

Comment: Personally, I'd overwrite the onDraw method, have it do that check there for the ==2.  Then you could call the .invalidate() method on your imageView class.

Comment: But the new answer should help.

Comment: @Holloway, I tried the setting imageview in the last, but when the touchCount becomes greater than 2, my second bitmap is not visible anymore.

Comment: I'll have to look at it again after work.  Hopefully you get it figured out before then though. :)

Comment: I'll appreciate your help on this

Comment: I want to show second bitmap and keep it there before adding others, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I overlay 2 images together

```
        // Get your images from their files
        final Bitmap iconL =
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
            getResourceID("alm_big", "drawable", ctx));
        final Bitmap bmpCombo =
            iconL.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        final Bitmap bmpTop =
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
            getResourceID(strIcon_Big, "drawable", ctx));

        // Use the canvas to combine them.
        // Start with the first in the constructor.
        final Canvas cnv = new Canvas(bmpCombo);

        // Then draw the second on top of that
        cnv.drawBitmap(bmpTop, 0f, 0f, null);

        // bmpCombo is now a composite of the two.
        bld.setLargeIcon(bmpCombo);
```